# Find sign of an integer in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, sign

Can we find  the sign of an inter in OCaml without using binary operations ? I mean It's easy to get the sign by comparing with 0. Are there any method other than that using match with command ? I tried the following

```
let sign n =
    let k = abs(n) in
    match k with
    | 0 -> 0
    | n -> 1
    | _ -> (-1);;
```

But it doesn't works for negative ones as it shows that last comparison is unused. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern-matching with the pattern `n` does not compare the value to that of the existing variable `n`. It binds a new variable `n` within the `->` block. The old variable `n` continues to exist and keeps its value, but is temporarily unaccessible though that name.

As a result, `match … with n -> …` always succeeds, because any expression is of the form `n` for a new variable `n`.

The `match` construct is not appropriate for identifying the sign of an integer. You would be better off simply writing `if n > 0 then 1 else if n < 0 then -1 else 0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pattern matching, you could try:

```
let sign n =
    match n with
    | 0 -> 0
    | _ -> (n / abs(n));
```

This returns 0 for 0,  -1 for negatives, and +1 for positives

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matching trick doesn't work as the pattern `| n ->` does not compare your value with n but instead creates a new n bound to k.

A simple workaround would be to use the `compare` function. It is not specified as such but does actually works this way:

```
let sign n = compare n 0;;
```